# ContextMenu as staticresource issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I've been scratching my head for a while at an issue i was having, eventually tracked it down to a problem with contextmenu's as a static resource.

The problem i'm having is that when i moved the contextmenu into a static resource, and used datatriggers to load a context menu based on the state of an object, the button commands seemed to get stuck on the datacontext bound on the first load, but the other binding's worked fine.

What i have is the following, a view which contains a listview using a custom item template, this item template is:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="appListTemplate">
    <Button cal:Message.Attach="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BBF7F7F7"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                                <Border CornerRadius="5" Height="35" Width="35" Background="SkyBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

                                <Label Content="{Binding AppName}" ToolTip="{Binding AppStatus}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0,0,0" FontSize="16"/>

                                <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" ToolTip="{Binding AppIconName}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Height="20" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>

                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Line Stroke="#FFCDCDCD" Stretch="Fill" X2="1" />
                                    <Line Stroke="#FFEAEAEA" Stretch="Fill" X2="1" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AppStatus}" Value="{x:Static enum:AppStatus.DISABLED}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Lime"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AppStatus}" Value="{x:Static enum:AppStatus.NOACCESS}">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NoAccessContextMenu}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AppStatus}" Value="{x:Static enum:AppStatus.INSTALLED}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=InstalledContextMenu}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AppStatus}" Value="{x:Static enum:AppStatus.NOTINSTALLED}">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=UninstalledContextMenu}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF7F7F7"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, depending on the status there is a different contextmenu loaded. these are defined as:

```
 <ContextMenu x:Key="InstalledContextMenu" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="RunApplication" Header="Run" cal:Message.Attach="Run"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Uninstall" cal:Message.Attach="Uninstall"/>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="UninstalledContextMenu" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="Install" Header="Install" cal:Message.Attach="Install"/>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="NoAccessContextMenu" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="RequestAccess" Header="Request Access" cal:Message.Attach="RequestAccess"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

The problem comes when you right click the first item in the list, it displays the options correctly E.G

```
SHIPPING
--------
Run
Uninstall
```

This work's 100%, however when you then right click on the second item in the list you get the following:

```
PROJECTS
--------
Run
Uninstall
```

as you can see, the appname binding updates fine, however when you click uninstall, it calls the uninstall method on the shipping VM, when it should be calling the uninstall on the projects VM. This will continue to happen with every item calling the methods on Shipping VM instead.

I'm at a total loss on what i can do about this, or even why it's happening. Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: A quick fix would be to `Bind` to a `SelectedItem` of the `ListView`.

Comment: There is already a binding for that, this style is in a separate stylesheet and the binding call directly to the viewmodel for each item in that listview, it works fine if i define the contextmenu directly inside the datatemplate, it's only the fact it's a static resource that causes issues.

Comment: @user1412240 have you any binding expression errors in your output window?

Comment: Nope, no errors. the binding works fine {Binding AppName} and point to the right datacontext, however the cal:Message.Attach will only ever call the methods on the first datacontext, so if I open the contextmenu for shipping, all other contextmenu commands on say Projects point to the shipping context, even when the appname binding correctly shows projects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Thanks to some hints from people, i've eventually tracked this down.
The issue is caused because the contextmenu is not the in visual tree, and microsofts "fix" is to make the contextmenu inherit it's parents datacontext, however this only ever happens once, and obviously when changing the datacontext, such as when changing selected item in a listview, the datacontext is never updated.

To solve this, i changed the contextmenu to the following.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="InstalledContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="RunApplication" Header="Run" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" cal:Message.Attach="Run"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Uninstall" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" cal:Message.Attach="Uninstall"/>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="UninstalledContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="Install" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"  Header="Install" cal:Message.Attach="Run"/>
</ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu x:Key="NoAccessContextMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" StaysOpen="False">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False"/>
    <Separator/>
    <MenuItem x:Name="RequestAccess" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" Header="Request Access" cal:Message.Attach="RequestAccess"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

As you can see, i now create my own binding for the datacontext and then setup the target context for my caliburn micro actions on each menuitem. It's a bit of an arse having to do this for each menu item, but seems to be the simplest fix.

Comment: Actually your `DataContext` is updated correctly, Proof: The text in menu items is changing. The problem here is `Micro` not picking up different DataContext hence calling actions on first DataContext.

Comment: See i thought about that as well, however as you mentioned the binding for the menuitem text is changing, which is also handled by caliburn.mirco

Comment: `<MenuItem Header="{Binding AppName}"` I think this means that the `Binding` engine is responsible for that.However `cal` might be intercepting that functionality I don't know. Personally I never used `cal`.

Comment: Unless i'm mistaken, that is handled by cal. I could be wrong which i must admit makes more sense in this situation :D